# How to get register model in uvm_sequence task in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to get registers in a sequence.
I declared the register model and made queue to put registers into the queue.
I thought that it works:

```
    uvm_reg_map     maps[$];
    uvm_reg         regs[$];
    uvm_reg_field   fields[$];
    string          mode[`UVM_REG_DATA_WIDTH];
    uvm_reg_data_t  dc_mask;
    uvm_reg_data_t  reset_val;
    int             n_bits;
    string          field_access;

    regmodel.get_map(maps);
    regmodel.get_registers(regs);
    regmodel.get_fields(fields);
```

I can check the registers:

```
foreach(regs[i]) begin
    `uvm_info("regs", $sformatf(" regisger = %s", regs[i].get_full_name()), UVM);
```

I would like to write with some randomized value by the `write()` method in a task.

```
task all_wr_pattern(uvm_reg_map  map,bit  pat);
       uvm_status_e status;
       uvm_reg_data_t val;  
      
      if(pat == 0)
         val = '1; 
      if(pat == 1) 
         void'(std::randomize(val));  
      else if(pat == 2)
          val = '0;
       regs.write(status, val, UVM_FRONTDOOR, map, this); 
   endtask
```

then I got this error message:

```
    regs.write(status, val, UVM_FRONTDOOR, map, this); 
          |
xmelab: *E,CUVUNF (./dma_reg_sequence.sv,137|16): Hierarchical name component lookup failed for 'regs' at '$unit_0x67f934e9'.
```

How do I correctly use the `write` method in a task?

I elaborate https://edaplayground.com/x/Dymm to help your understand.

Comment: I fixed typo and check CUVUNF error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the relevant lines of your code:

```
uvm_reg         regs[$];
regmodel.get_registers(regs);
   regs.write(status, val, UVM_FRONTDOOR, map, this);
```

The 1st line declares a variable which represents a **queue** of registers (type uvm_reg).

The 2nd line populates the queue variable with a set of registers from your register model.

The error occurs in the 3rd line because you are attempting to call the `write` method on a **queue** of registers, which is illegal.  You can only call `write` on a single register.  For example, the 1st register in the queue is denoted by `regs[0]`:

```
   regs[0].write(status, val, UVM_FRONTDOOR, map, this);
```

You can use `foreach` to loop through all registers, as you did when you checked them: `regs[i]`

Comment: Thanks for clarify it,  I confused that Bit bash sequence.